# Getting an error while using Pandas.Series.quantile()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As per the documentation on the Pandas page, we are allowed to pass a list of values to the quantile function in Pandas series.

```
>>> s = Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> s.quantile(.5)
    2.5
>>> s.quantile([.25, .5, .75])
0.25    1.75
0.50    2.50
0.75    3.25

dtype: float64
```

While trying the same on my system, I get the following error.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> s
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64
>>> s.quantile(0.5)
2.5
>>> s.quantile([0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1324, in quantile
    result = _quantile(valid_values, q * 100)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/compat/scipy.py", line 66, in scoreatpercentile
    idx = per / 100. * (values.shape[0] - 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me it works in Python 2.7.6 and pandas 0.17.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's an issue with the version of SciPy that you are using. Just check it out, which version of SciPy, your current version of pandas is dependent on and accordingly update the SciPy library.